# Is there a fractal origami shape that trades volume for area to always keep a flat surface when expanded?

Tags: general-topology, fractals

I'm thinking of something like a 2.5D sierpienski type shape.

The idea is to enable an lcd type screen that could unfold to "any" size by unpacking space filling elements packed in 3d to a 2d surface as it expands by a user pulling it open.

Any resources on how to find an l-system? Or similar for creating something like this?

Comment: My understanding is that a fractal pattern wg, hexagons linked by flexible edges would work fairly well in this case - if we can constrain the packing 2D-3D on one side and possibly related to that supply a resistance/spring force on each boundary to create a space filling fractal packing.

Comment: This TED talk might help you. It seems to provide some examples similar to what you're trying to do: http://www.ted.com/talks/robert_lang_folds_way_new_origami.html